# Are "embarassing" and "bewildering" synonyms?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

The dictionary that I'm using says those meanings are synonyms. Is there no difference between them?

I'd also like to know if perplexing could a be synonym of *embarassing* and *bewildering*.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It will help us help you if you can identify what meanings you have read for each, and perhaps give us some context, so we understand better the problem you're having with these words. I also encourage you to  take a few minutes to do the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to use this site.

Comment: They are quite different.  Being bewildered means you are confused by something -- the reason may be quite justified and those around you might very well understand the reason.  Being embarrassed means that you feel you have done something that others would disapprove of (or at least find comical, at your expense).  It's a (hopefully mild) form of shame.

Comment: What dictionary are you using?

Comment: Totally. I should throw my dictionary away

Answer (score 2):

“They are quite different. Being bewildered means you are confused by something — the reason may be quite justified and those around you might very well understand the reason. Being embarrassed means that you feel you have done something that others would disapprove of (or at least find comical, at your expense). It's a (hopefully mild) form of shame.”

—Hot Licks